# PL/SQL Control Structure - LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have about 94,000 records that need to be deleted, but I have been told not to delete all at once because it will slow the performance due to the delete trigger. What would be the best solution to accomplish this? I was thinking of an additional loop after the commit of 1000, but not too sure how to implement or know if that will reduce performance even more.

```
DECLARE  
  CURSOR CLEAN IS
  SELECT EMP_ID, ACCT_ID FROM RECORDS_TO_DELETE F; --Table contains the records that needs to be deleted.
  COUNTER INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
  FOR F IN CLEAN LOOP
    COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
    DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE EMP_ID = F.EMP_ID AND ACCT_ID = F.ACCT_ID;         

    IF MOD(COUNTER, 1000) = 0 THEN     
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read a bit about BULK COLLECT statements in oracle. This is commonly considered as proper way working with large tables.

Example:

```
    LOOP
        FETCH c_delete BULK COLLECT INTO t_delete LIMIT l_delete_buffer;

        FORALL i IN 1..t_delete.COUNT
            DELETE ps_al_chk_memo
             WHERE ROWID = t_delete (i);

            COMMIT;
        EXIT WHEN c_delete%NOTFOUND;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_delete;
```

Comment: Don't you think executing `Commit` after each record deletion will impact the performance?  That's ~94k commit transactions. Won't single `commit` be sufficient in this case?

Comment: Point here is that every chunk is limited with l_delete_buffer, so at least whole database will be not locked. When you will have commit only once on whole database - then table will be locked unless all triggers will be processed for all records.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single statement, this should be the fastest way in any kind:

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE (EMP_ID, ACCT_ID) =ANY (SELECT EMP_ID, ACCT_ID FROM RECORDS_TO_DELETE)
```

Comment: Usually people who think deleting lots of records at once will take a long time have not tried it.  So I agree with do it in one statement.  And ask if the delete trigger could be temporarily disabled safely while your statement runs.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can see the volume of record is not that much so can still go with SQL not by PLSQL.Whenever possible try SQL. I think it should not cause that much performance impact.

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM RECORDS_TO_DELETE F
WHERE EMP_ID = F.EMP_ID 
AND ACCT_ID= F.ACCT_ID);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if this may really slow down your application's database, can't you just schedule it for execution for let's say midnight? or if this is worldwide application when you have to keep the performance 24h/day, just find some off pick hours... and stick to the SQL whenever possible, really... :)